# Android LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener)

Tags: android, gps, listener, locationmanager

hi guys I have created a background service which gets the person location and if the distance between the device to the destination is smaller i request location updates more often and I am using the removeUpdates(LocationListener) method... the problem is that i noticed that the listener keeps getting updates and the more the loop is going it keeps get more and more updates. does anyone have any idea why this method doesn't work?

Here is my method for using the new location.

```
    void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location){
    manager.removeUpdates(listener);
    mLocation = location;
    currentLat = location.getLatitude();
    currentLong = location.getLongitude();
    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLong, gateLat, gateLong, results);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentDistanceFromDestination = results[0];
    Log.d("Current Location", "Lat:"+currentLat+"   Long:"+currentLong);
    Log.d("Destination Distance", currentDistanceFromDestination+"");
    if(currentDistanceFromDestination<3000){
        if(currentDistanceFromDestination<50){
            Log.d("50m closer", "Calling");

            startActivity(callIntent);
            stopSelf();
        }
        if(currentDistanceFromDestination<800){
            Log.d("800m closer", "Started listening every 10 seconds.");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentDistanceFromDestination+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 ,90 , listener);
        }else{
            Log.d("3000m closer", "Started listening every 25 seconds");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentDistanceFromDestination+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 25 * 1000, 300, listener);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It might start listening to updates again, since you have             `manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 25 * 1000, 300, listener);`

Comment: hmmm ye it suppose to listen and it does so, but it doesn't remove any updates

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you initiate the value of your listener between calls?
it might not be the same object so it cannot remove updates to it.
In that case the old listener will still be getting updates with you unable to remove them.